# simple obj-c naming question

Tags: objective-c

This question is more to figure out how to look up classes and objects in objective-c but i lack the knowledge to figure out how to look this up so i pose the question here.

In .Net if i had a MyObject.MyValue the MyValue would be called a property, and I could look this up in MSDN.  In java i would check the javadocs online (and that property would have to be a value).

With objective-c that is called a ? and if i wanted to look it up i would look where?

Example:

```
//Object.???
UIImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In obj-c it's called a "property" and you would look it up either [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or in the developer documentation in Xcode by going to "Help -> Documentation"

I prefer using the built-in documentation, it's super fast and very well organized.

Answer (score 1):

hover your mouse over "backgroundColor" and hit "option" and mouse click to bring up the documentation.  The documentation will tell you more about the class property or method.